# Finding out who is online using sessions in PHP. Is this a good way?

Tags: php, performance, session-state

I have a file base session mechanism in my PHP web application. I want to figure out if a user is online, idle, or logged out. Currently I have two solutions in mind but don't know which one is better. Also I don't know if there is an alternative which works better than these two. My main point is, I don't want to store sessions in DB, so I want a solution that uses file base sessions.

**Solution 1:** I create session files based on user_id which is unique, then each time a user does something, I update the timestamp on the session, then that causes the session file to be updated/written on disk again. When I want to figure out if a user is online, I use his user_id to read the session file last timestamp, if it's smaller than 5min, I assume he is online, if it's more than 5min and less than 10min, I assume he is idle, anything beyond that I assume the user is out.

**Solution 2:** I do the same thing by having a last_login field in user table, each time user does something on the site, or views some pages, I update that field with the latest timestamp, now if I want to see that user is online, I just check his last_login timestamp to see if his time fits into either of that online, idle, or logout state which I explained in Solution 1

So my question is, which one is going to be faster and with less overhead. My web site has 5000 members, probably 700 to 1200 logged in members per day. I have a VPS but moving to a dedicated server soon. So any suggestion other than those two solution ? and which one you choose ?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: I use to work with sql database, i don't see a fast way to search inside many files for a time statement. But just a though i've at first, what about a session folder where you can write sessions files by date so you list all sessions with < 5 min timestamp and names inside those files ?

Comment: that is what meant, but I wanted to user read file timestamp to get the file latest accessed time. So when the session is updated in memory, php will write the changes to the file, therefore the file timestamp gets updated and can be sorted by time.

Answer (score 0):

Track the session in the database along with the normal session handler. Can be done in a memory table if you don't need to store anything permanently.

Answer (score 0):

What about using cookies?

Use a cookie to identify unique users, and then just keep track of the last time accessed a PHP page. Then come up with a timeout mechanism - for example, if they have not accessed a page in 15 minutes then they are removed from the count.

How to set a cookie:

```
<?php
//Set a cookie which will expire when the browser is closed
setcookie('mycookie', 'myvalue');

//Set a cookie which expires in about a year
setcookie('longtime', 'nextyear', time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
?>
```

A good example for what you need:

```
<?php
//First we need to check if the user has visited before
//Let's use 'visittime' as the name for our cookie

if(isset($_COOKIE['visittime']))
{
  echo 'Welcome back!<br>';

  //Calculate how long is since the users last visit
  //We can do this simply by subtracting the last visit
  //time from the current time
  $timeElapsed = time() - $_COOKIE['visittime'];

  echo 'It has been ' . $timeElapsed . ' seconds since your last visit.';
}
else
{
  echo 'I see you are new here';
}

//Set the current time as a cookie and make it expire much later.
$nextYear = time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
setcookie('visittime', time(), $nextYear);
?>
```